# Valgrind reporting "unlocked a not-locked lock" at pthreads_cleanup_push around pthread_cond_wait?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, valgrind

Here is a snippet from problematic thread:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(data->mutex));
for(;;)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push((void(*)(void *))pthread_mutex_unlock, (void*)&(data->mutex));
    while(data->fifo_cnt == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&(data->cond_write), &(data->mutex));
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

    // Do stuff

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(data->mutex));
    data->fifo_cnt -= write_len;
    pthread_cond_signal(&(data->cond_written));
}
```

Man for pthread_cond_wait states that when thread is canceled (while waiting on cond var.), associated mutex is reacquired before running cleanup handlers. So there should be a cleanup handler that unlocks this mutex...

However when I cancel my thread, valgrind reports:

```
==4094== Thread #10 unlocked a not-locked lock at 0x61ED02C
==4094==    at 0x402577B: pthread_mutex_unlock (hg_intercepts.c:610)
==4094==    by 0x804CA5D: write_thread (rip.c:60)
==4094==    by 0x4028734: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:221)
==4094==    by 0x404F7AF: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==4094==    by 0x41548FD: clone (clone.S:130)
```

rip.cd:60 lies exactly at pthread_cleanup_push()
This is correct - cleanup handler is called from inside of this macro, **but why Valgrind thinks it's unlocked?**